# Warning - CloudML runtime version 1.11 with GPU crashes (CuDNN error)

Tags: google-cloud-ml

When using CloudML for training with 1 GPU (`BASIC_GPU` tier) and runtime version 1.11, I get the following error, then the job fails.

`Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.0.5 but source was compiled with: 7.3.0. CuDNN library major and minor version needs to match or have higher minor version in case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library. If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.`

Any idea on what could cause the problem?

Note that the job runs well with runtime version 1.10 using the same tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue! We have noticed it and are working on matching the CuDNN version in the binary. This should be fixed in our next release.

Comment: Thanks for your reactivity

Comment: Hi @lwz1992, do you plan to release 1.11 soon?

Comment: The engineering team is working on it now, you should expect it to be available in couple of weeks. Please check https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/release-notes for the latest update.